# Message not received TCP

Tags: c#, .net, tcpclient, tcplistener, ip-camera

My `IP-Camera` is configured to send alarm messages to my computer.

***IPAddress of camera: 10.251.51.1

IPAddress of my computer: 10.251.51.136***

The camera can be configured to send messages to any port on my computer.

So, I set the alarm destination to my computer's IP Address: `10.251.51.136` at `port 3487`.

Now, what should be done at my computer to get the message sent by the camera ?

I tried to write a `TCPListener` from `MSDN` and the code is below:

```
                Int32 port = 3487;
                IPAddress localAddr = IPAddress.Parse("10.251.51.136");

                // TcpListener server = new TcpListener(port);
                server = new TcpListener(localAddr, port);
                server.Start();

                // Start listening for client requests.

                // Buffer for reading data
                Byte[] bytes = new Byte[256];
                String data = null;

                // Enter the listening loop.
                while (true)
                {
                    Console.Write("Waiting for a connection... ");

                    // Perform a blocking call to accept requests.
                    // You could also user server.AcceptSocket() here.
                    TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();
                    Console.WriteLine("Connected!");

                server.Start();
                    data = null;

                    // Get a stream object for reading and writing
                    NetworkStream stream = client.GetStream();

                    int i;

                    // Loop to receive all the data sent by the client.
                    while ((i = stream.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length)) != 0)
                    {
                        // Translate data bytes to a ASCII string.
                        data = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bytes, 0, i);
                        Console.WriteLine("Received: {0}", data);

                        // Process the data sent by the client.
                        data = data.ToUpper();

                        byte[] msg = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(data);

                        // Send back a response.
                        stream.Write(msg, 0, msg.Length);
                        Console.WriteLine("Sent: {0}", data);
                    }

                    // Shutdown and end connection
                    client.Close();
                }
            }
            catch (SocketException e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("SocketException: {0}", e);
            }
            finally
            {
                // Stop listening for new clients.
                server.Stop();
            }
```

But this does not seem to be working.

Or is my entire approach flawed ? Should i implement `TCPListener` or `TCPServer` instead for my scenario above?

Any pointers why?

Comment: What doesn't work? Are you able to estabilish a connection, are you able to receive data? Does the loop end prematurely? Are you sure the camera uses TCP, rather than say UDP?

Comment: @Luaan: Ya, i checked with the camera. It uses `TCP`. I wonder my code is correct ?

Comment: @Luaan: On putting breakpoint, the execution just keeps on waiting after this line `TcpClient client = server.AcceptTcpClient();`

Comment: Looks fine to me. You're doing a lot of unnecessary stuff, but it wouldn't cause you to be unable to accept TCP clients. Have you actually allowed the incoming port on your firewall? Try disabling the firewall for a bit to make sure it's not interfering. If that doesn't help, try Wireshark or a similar tool to see if the TCP request even reaches your computer.

Comment: @Luaan: Thanks Luaan. I will disable my firewall and then take a look at `WireShark` and will come back :)